How to use @for with NgClass in angular 18
I have the following HTML structure in my template:
<tbody>
    @for(element of elements.value; track $index; let idx = $index, let isEven = $even){
       <tr *ngClass="isEven ? 'some styles here' : 'some other styles otherwise' ">
       <tr>
    }
<tbody>

The problem is in this case I'm getting the following error:
Property 'isEven' does not exist on type 'MyCoomponentName'

Could someone explain how to use this new @for with the ngClass? My main goal is to paint even <tr> of one color and odds of another, maybe there is another way to do it but not sure.
I tried *ngClass={{isEven ? '' : ''}} but didn't worked but not sure that's even possible.

You should follow the same syntax that is mentioned in the documentation.
Contextual variables in @for blocks
The ngClass directive is designed for property binding and usually is not a structural directive (has the suffix * to it). so replace it with [ngClass].
The ngClass is designed for conditionally adding classes, if you want to conditionally add styles, you should prefer [ngStyle] instead.
<table>
  <tbody>
      @for(element of elements.value; track element.id; let idx = $index, isEven = $even){
        <tr [ngClass]="isEven ? 'red' : 'yellow' ">
          <td>{{element.value}}</td>
        <tr>
      }
  <tbody>
</table>

Full Code:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  styles: [
    `
  .red {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  `,
  ],
  template: `
    <table>
      <tbody>
          @for(element of elements.value; track element.id; let idx = $index, isEven = $even){
            <tr [ngClass]="isEven ? 'red' : 'yellow' ">
              <td>{{element.value}}</td>
            <tr>
          }
      <tbody>
    </table>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  elements = {
    value: [
      { id: 1, value: 'one' },
      { id: 2, value: 'two' },
      { id: 3, value: 'three' },
    ],
  };
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Yeap it worked like a charm! thanks!
